# Retrieve Projects setting from custom TFS XAML code

Tags: tfs

From a custom TFS XAML file, how do I retrieve the Projects setting?  I don't see it in the list of WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ProjectsToBuild argument (type of String[]).